# Jquery - When invoking a Ajax Load Req; Best way to prevent multiple invokes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link 'hrefs="javascript:callFunc()">' that invokes the function 'callFunc()';

```
function callFunc(){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "call.php",
           data: "i="+i+add,
           success: function(msg){

                $('#content').html(msg);
           }
         });
}
```

The issue: When the user click's that link 4 times, the callFunc is going to invoke 4 times, sending 4* the post via ajax.

Anyway to lock this down?

*Beaware that the link could be through out the page too; And there could be similar functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
window.funcRunning = false;

function callFunc(){
    if(window.funcRunning == false) {
    window.funcRunning = true;
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "call.php",
           data: "i="+i+add,
           success: function(msg){

                $('#content').html(msg);
                window.funcRunning = false;
           }
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: is window.X the same as document.X ?

Comment: JavaScript always has a highest level `global` object - `window` is that object in the context of a browser. `document` is a property of `window` so they aren't the same. However, both `window.X` and `document.X` should be globally available as `document.X` is just a shortcut for `window.document.X`

Answer (score 0):

Have the event handler disable the link, or ever better replace it with "Please wait…" or other appropriate feedback message.